# Javascript addEventListener Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my header on a website to hide when scrolling down and to re-appear when scrolling up. The only issue is, I cannot figure out how to use the below code to achieve this. I have searched far and wide and have not found a solution. Any help is appreciated and do realize I am a complete noob when it comes to this. :)

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(throttleTimeout, function() {
        //...
        if (wScrollCurrent <= 0) // scrolled to the very top; element sticks to the top
          removeElementClass(element, elClassHidden);

        else if (wScrollDiff > 0 && hasElementClass(element, elClassHidden)) // scrolled up; element slides in
          removeElementClass(element, elClassHidden);

        else if (wScrollDiff < 0) // scrolled down
        {
          if (wScrollCurrent + wHeight >= dHeight && hasElementClass(element, elClassHidden)) // scrolled to the very bottom; element slides in
            removeElementClass(element, elClassHidden);

          else // scrolled down; element slides out
            addElementClass(element, elClassHidden);
        }
        //...
      }));
```

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: Gray;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.header--hidden {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
    <header class="header" role="banner">
      <div id=Image>
        <a href="http://localhost/lab/">
          <img src="http://localhost/lab/includes/images/logo-small.png">
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id="menu">



        <ul id="menu">
          <li><a href="http://localhost/lab">Home</a>
          </li>

          <li><a href="http://localhost/lab/projects">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://localhost/lab/videos">Videos</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://localhost/lab/contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="http://localhost/lab/about">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>


      </div>
    </header>
```

[View the site from which this code was taken.](http://osvaldas.info/auto-hide-sticky-header)

Comment: Where does the `throttle()` function come from?  That isn't part of a standard browser environment.  And, you aren't really telling us what the specific problem is with the code you have.  Are you getting errors?  If no errors, what do you observe?  What do you expect?

Comment: @jfriend00 I believe the throttle function is to listen only at a specific interval...? The problem with the code is that it does not work [to my knowledge]. The header is static at the top of the page and does not hide itself.

Comment: This requires the first steps of debugging.  Is your code getting called?  If it's getting called, does it add/remove the desired classes at the appropriate place?  If yes, then does your CSS do what it's supposed to when the classes are added.  If no to any of the other questions, you take a different investigative branch.  Since you have not provided a working snippet or jsFiddle or something similar, we cannot debug it for you.  Hint, you can start with `console.log()` statements for basic debugging, then advance to breakpoints in the debugger and stepping through code.

Comment: Also, we have no idea what `wScrollCurrent` or `wScrollDiff` are.

Comment: throttle() is part of underscore.js

Comment: @jfriend00 Here is the site from which I got my examples: http://osvaldas.info/auto-hide-sticky-header

Comment: That's an incomplete code example in that web page.  The variables I asked about above are not declared.

Comment: @jfriend00 I apologize. I have very little knowledge of javascript and am fully confused as to how to make this project work. Do you know of any sources which will give me a good explanation as to how to accomplish my goal with animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the point of that site you reference is because they aren't showing you the whole code.  If you go to their demo page and look at View/Source, you see the whole listener code as this:

```
( function ( document, window, index )
    {

    'use strict';

    var elSelector  = '.header',
        element     = document.querySelector( elSelector );

    if( !element ) return true;

    var elHeight        = 0,
        elTop           = 0,
        dHeight         = 0,
        wHeight         = 0,
        wScrollCurrent  = 0,
        wScrollBefore   = 0,
        wScrollDiff     = 0;

    window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function()
    {
        elHeight        = element.offsetHeight;
        dHeight         = document.body.offsetHeight;
        wHeight         = window.innerHeight;
        wScrollCurrent  = window.pageYOffset;
        wScrollDiff     = wScrollBefore - wScrollCurrent;
        elTop           = parseInt( window.getComputedStyle( element ).getPropertyValue( 'top' ) ) + wScrollDiff;

        if( wScrollCurrent <= 0 ) // scrolled to the very top; element sticks to the top
            element.style.top = '0px';

        else if( wScrollDiff > 0 ) // scrolled up; element slides in
            element.style.top = ( elTop > 0 ? 0 : elTop ) + 'px';

        else if( wScrollDiff < 0 ) // scrolled down
        {
            if( wScrollCurrent + wHeight >= dHeight - elHeight )  // scrolled to the very bottom; element slides in
                element.style.top = ( ( elTop = wScrollCurrent + wHeight - dHeight ) < 0 ? elTop : 0 ) + 'px';

            else // scrolled down; element slides out
                element.style.top = ( Math.abs( elTop ) > elHeight ? -elHeight : elTop ) + 'px';
        }

        wScrollBefore = wScrollCurrent;
    });

}( document, window, 0 ));
```

I can't say if this will entirely fix the problem because they may have given you incomplete code in other areas too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience! I am very confused. I have put together an example using your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=pix5wAIhDS  And it seems to work as desired. I have the same code, however, in my site and the header stays static.

Comment: @QuestionAsker - We can't really say what isn't working in your site without seeing the actual page in the site.  Are there errors reported in the debug console?

Comment: @QuestionAsker - You need to learn how to look in the debug console for script errors.  This line of code causes an error: `if( !element ) return true;` because it's not in a function like it is elsewhere.  You can probably just remove that line of code.

Comment: @jsfriend00 Thank so much...that was the fix! I'll look into the debug console...I've never heard of such a thing for java script. I appreciate your patience with someone so incompetent as I.

Comment: @QuestionAsker - I also modified my answer so it will work with that line of code.